# Can't uninstall Microsoft Office 2007

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, uninstall

When I try to uninstall Microsoft Office 2007 Ultimate from Windows Vista Home Premium through the Control Panel, I keep getting the following message:

```
Setup could not find any available products to install. 
Please contact your system administrator.
```

But I'm my own system administrator and I totally don't know what to do. The only reason why I'm uninstalling Office is so I get my activation back as I want to install it on another machine.

Anyone know what may be going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what the error is - you can try reinstalling over the top then uninstalling if you want to remove, However... if the reason is to get the activation back, this will not work.

Office and other Microsoft products do not report back when uninstalled. If you have a retail copy, you are allowed to reinstall it as many times as you like on as many computers as you like, so long as it is only in one place at any one time.

Activation should not fail, but if it does, simply ring the free phone number and they will either give you a code or a new serial key, however, I doubt it will fail.

Comment: Man, I wish I knew that earlier! I got my copy through the Ultimate Steal thing so it should be the same as retail. I'll just load Linux here and install Office on my other PC. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the uninstallation with [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/):

> Revo Uninstaller Pro helps you to uninstall software and remove
>   unwanted programs installed on your computer easily! Even if you have
>   problems uninstalling and cannot uninstall them from "Windows Add or
>   Remove Programs" control panel applet.